# Lambda Clound Watch Logging

Tags: amazon-web-services, lambda, amazon-cloudwatch

I have a python lambda function which is triggered by a call to API gateway. print statements were being generated as logs in cloud watch just fine but suddenly stopped and cloud watch only logs the START event. However, if I trigger the lambda from the Test button on the console it logs just fine. The function also works as expected when I post data to the API gateway. I was doing some testing and was deleting logs and uploading lambda code back and forth but can't imagine that this could break it. 
Thank you for your help!